# Efecto blur sobre menu overlay

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Alguien sabe como hacer un menu overlay, que cuando le de click, el fondo tenga un efecto blur.

Ejemplo menu overlay, coloco en la clase overlay rgba(0,0,0,0.5), pero si coloco sobre esta clase

```
filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
```

solo el texto del menu se vuelve blur, hay alguna manera para que usando javascript pueda darle click al menu y el fondo se vuelva blur?

Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema. Además, mira [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/133925/250) porque creo que es el mismo problema que intentas resolver (las soluciones que encontrarás allí te podrán más o menos servir).

Comment: Deberías añadir el código del ejemplo que planteas y te recomiendo echarle un ojo a lo que te recomienda @AlvaroMontoro